# How to transform a matrix into a fixed point form

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, fixed-point-theorems

As asked in the title, how to transform a $3 × 3$ matrix into the fixed point form $x=Tx+b$?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: "Let A be the matrix whose rows are (2 0 1), (1 2 0), (1 1 3). When Ax=b is put into the fixed-point form x = Tx+v, calculate the (usual) norm of the matrix T for the Jacobi method and for the Gauss-Seidel method to see that the latter can indeed be strictly smaller than the former. " This is the original question, but I am not sure what it means by putting that equation into the fixed point form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
Ax=b \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (D+N)x = b
\end{align}
where $D$ is the diagonal of $A$ and $N$ is everything else. Then it follows
\begin{align}
x = D^{-1}b - D^{-1}Nx. 
\end{align}
This is called the Jacobi fixed-point form.

Comment: Oh I got it. So T is equal to $D^{-1}N$ and b is equal to $D^{-1}b$?

Comment: Be careful. $T = -D^{-1}N$

Comment: What if some element of the diagonal is $0$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Then you can't use Jacobi method.

Comment: @JackyChong Thanks!